# Some wordplay that'll make your eyes roll (among other things...)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Turn me right and I was nearly frozen,
Turn me left and I'm open,
And I was once my own reflection,
Well... Before the revolution

Hint 1:

> If you massively rearrange me, I can be American

Hint 2:

> The term "revolution" refers to a political revolution.

Comment: I realise this is very late, but **please don't edit the answer into the question**. You can post an answer to your own question, and if you want to avoid earning points from it, you can click the box to make that answer "community wiki". Answers don't belong in questions.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by the OP in an edit to the question:

> I am the French Flag, vertical bands of blue/white/red.
>  Chile's flag used to be horizontal blue/white/red bars.
>  A common flag declaring a place "open" is red/white/blue horizontal bars.
>  France's flag was, for a time, a reflection of its current self, prior to the French Revolution

Answer (score 0):

This might not be right, but are you

> Wassamassaw

Method

> I looked up colonies with palindromic names, and the wikipedia entry on places with palindromic names included Wassamassaw, which was a colonial era American colony. The line saying that your open on the left implies that the open prairies are on the left (?). The frozen bit might refer to the fact the borders frozen on the coast because it can’t extend further (?).

Disclaimer

> This is based mostly on the last 3 lines.